# How to use sudo as an argument in a cap shell command?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

When I try to run a cap shell command that uses *sudo* as an argument rather than a command, substitution that is only relevant for sudo when it is used as a command is performed.

Example:

```
$ cap shell
cap> rpm -q sudo
```

That fails since shell.rb contains

```
command = command.gsub(/\bsudo\b/, "sudo -p '#{configuration.sudo_prompt}'")
```

which mangles the command into

```
rpm -q sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''
```

The rpm command expects a package file when it encounters the -p option.  There is no package so it fails.

Similar issues occur when I try to run `grep sudo`, etc. from cap shell.

Is there a way to use *sudo* as an argument in a cap shell command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS, this problem seems to be a bug in Capistrano.  So, please report to [the BTS](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues).

Anyway, you can work-around this problem by overriding the private method `Capistrano::Shell::exec_command()` in your own `cap` command.

1. create a file called `mycap.rb`
2. copy the original `/usr/bin/cap` in your `mycap.rb`
3. add `require 'capistrano/shell'`
4. add `exec_command()` in your `mycap.rb`
5. replace the regexp `/\bsudo\b/` with something like `/^sudo\b/`
6. execute `mycap.rb` instead of the original `cap` command

The contents of mycap.rb should be like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'capistrano/cli'
require 'capistrano/shell'

module Capistrano
  class Shell
    private

    def exec_command(command, servers)
      command = command.gsub(/^sudo\b/, "sudo -p '#{configuration.sudo_prompt}'")
      processor = configuration.sudo_behavior_callback(Configuration.default_io_proc)
      sessions = servers.map { |server| configuration.sessions[server] }
      options = configuration.add_default_command_options({})
      cmd = Command.new(command, sessions, options.merge(:logger => configuration.logger), &processor)
      previous = trap("INT") { cmd.stop! }
      cmd.process!
    rescue Capistrano::Error => error
      warn "error: #{error.message}"
    ensure
      trap("INT", previous)
    end
  end
end

Capistrano::CLI.execute
```

Note that `\b` is replaced by `^` in `command.gsub()`.  But everything else is the same.

Comment: hmm... 1) I tested without `require 'rubygems'` and worked.  not sure why. 2) ah, the original author is not maintaining capistrano anymore.  better to report to [the github issue tracker](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues). I've updated the url.

Comment: Yes. There is no easy way for Capistrano to know the string "sudo" is actually a command which remote shell is about to execute, or just a string / argument.  You can have the same parser as your remote shell, but that depends user's settings.  The reason you need to know whether sudo is actually executed at remote side or not is that you need to add prompt option.  Can you, as a user, supply the option if and when you need instead of having Capistrano guess?